# leanModal.js - Close Modal on X Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

Need a bit of help with [this query](https://github.com/FinelySliced/leanModal.js/issues/4)

Any way you guys can help?

-R

Comment: Please post your question here, rather than a link to your question on another site.

Comment: Apologies. Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must modify the `leanModal.js` source and add an `<img>` with some styling and `click()` handler calling `close_modal()`.

**Code:**

```
$("<img />").css({
  // styling for the img
  'position': 'fixed', 'top':  o.top + 'px', 'left': '50%'
}).click(function() {
  // onclick behaviour - just close it
  close_modal(modal_id); 
  // icon URL   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
}).attr('src', 'http://bit.ly/ttN6Qs').appendTo($(modal_id));
```

See working code **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/d7r8R/)**.

Styling and icon-placement is very primitive, but you should be able to modify it how you like. It is only a demonstration :).

Comment: What a guy - this is perfect. I altered the code slightly to use a div element with an X as the content, rather than an image. Thanks, man - brilliant help.

Comment: Also, do you know with this overlay, because of the length, on smaller screens a lot gets cut off but when you scroll it scrolls the background content, rather than the overlay content. Might be to do with the fixed position, but any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this wasn't a feature when the question was posed, but you can now tell leanModal which class should trigger the closing of the modal window. From their website: "In the spirit of keeping things simple, there are only two three options involved: vertical position of the modal element in relation to the document body, the overlay opacity (default is 0.5), and a close button option (default null). You can override these defaults by passing your desired values to the function, like so:
$("#trigger_id").leanModal({ top : 200, overlay : 0.4, closeButton: ".modal_close" });

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did for the div element:

```
$("<div >").css({
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    //'top': o.top + 'px',
                    'top': '-20px',
                    'right': '20px'
                }).click(function() {
                    // onclick behaviour - just close it
                    close_modal(modal_id);
                }).attr('class', 'cross-close').appendTo($(modal_id));

                $(modal_id).fadeTo(200, 1);

                e.preventDefault();

            });

        });
```

And had this has my CSS...

```
.cross-close:before {
content: "x";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same issue, and resolved it by simulating the click on the overlay. For example, any link or image could be used and you simply add an onclick event:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="$('#lean_overlay').click();">Close</a>
```

or

`<img src="" onclick="$('#lean_overlay').click();" />`

Seems to work well :D